# Replacing Forefront TMG with Apache/Squid Reverse Proxy and ldap authentication

Tags: apache, authentication, reverse-proxy, claims-based-identity

I'm looking to replace Forefront TMG with and open source solution (probably apache or squid) but I'm not to sure how to go about it. Currently TMG sits in front of share point 2010 and acts as a reverse proxy. TMG presents a login page that authenticates via ldap. I'm not exactly sure if TMG is handling the ldap authentication or if its sharepoint. Sharepoint is setup to use Claims Authentication with Windows Authentication/NTLM.

I'm guessing that TMG passes the user credentials along with domain from the form to Sharepoint which then authenticates to the ldap server and then this returns either a token or cookie for an authenticated user.

Does anyone have an idea how to replicate this minus TMG and in its place apache or squid and/or combination of?